# Is .NET DateTime truncating my seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to format some precise dates, converting them from a Unix timestamp to a DateTime object. I noticed that the AddSeconds method has an overload that accepts a floating point number.

My expectation is that I may pass in a number such as `1413459415.93417` and it will give me a DateTime object with tick-level precision. Is this a decent assumption, or `does the AddSeconds method still provide no better than millisecond precision?` In the conversion, do I have to add the ticks myself?

My conversion code is below:

```
public static DateTime CalendarDateFromUnix(double unixTime)
    {
        DateTime calendarTime = UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(unixTime);
        return calendarTime;
    }
```

I expect to format the ToString of this date like `16 Oct 2014 11:36:55.93417` using the format string below:

```
dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffff
```

Instead of giving me `16 Oct 2014 11:36:55.93417`, it is giving me `16 Oct 2014 11:36:55.93400`

Am I doing something wrong or is .NET truncating my floating-point seconds representation? I am new to .NET, so the former is quite possible.

Thanks

Comment: [status-broken-by-design]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation of [`DateTime.AddSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The value parameter is rounded to the nearest millisecond.

An alternative would be to multiply by `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond` and then add that to the ticks of `UnixEpoch`:

```
return new DateTime(
    UnixEpoch.Ticks + (long) (unixTime * Timespan.TicksPerSecond),
    DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I must have missed that in the docs. Do you have any idea why Microsoft doesn't implement a conversion to the more precise measurements in the DateTime object? Even tough it's trivial to implement manually, I think the functionality should be there. After all, isn't C# all about saving developer time?

Comment: @CanadaIT: I *suspect* it's because it's easy to end up with sub-second values that you don't actually want due to `double` imprecision. Not sure though. If you're looking for a better date/time API for .NET, you might want to look at my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project :)